# Can't get string from If statement

Tags: c#

My compiler is throwing an error:

> The name 'myIP' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

Below is the code:

```
string HostName = Dns.GetHostName();//get HOSTNAME
    string osVer = System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString();         

        if (osVer.StartsWith("10")) 
        {
         MessageBox.Show("Windows 10");
        string myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName).AddressList[2].ToString();// Get the IP
        }

        else if (osVer.StartsWith("6"))
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Win7!");
        string myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName).AddressList[3].ToString();// Get the IP

        }
         else
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Non Complient Operating System");
         }

         byte myIP3 = IPAddress.Parse(myIP).GetAddressBytes()[2];//Gets third octet of IP
         byte myIP2 = IPAddress.Parse(myIP).GetAddressBytes()[1];//Gets second octet of IP
         byte myIP1 = IPAddress.Parse(myIP).GetAddressBytes()[0];//Gets first octet of IP
```

Comment: Move the declaration of `string myIP` out of your if statements. It's only visible within them, which means it's not available to use in your last three lines. Re-read your lessons on variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string myIp; <-- declare here
    if (osVer.StartsWith("10")) 
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Windows 10");
    myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName).AddressList[2].ToString();// Get the IP
    }

    else if (osVer.StartsWith("6"))
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Win7!");
    myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName).AddressList[3].ToString();// Get the IP

    }
    else {
     //BTW. What to do here?
     myIP = ?
    }
```

Comment: As it stands this isn't a good answer - you've told him the solution but not **why** it's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Much like the others have said, the "myIp" variable should be defined before the if-statements as the if-statements create their own local scopes.

Now as you are defining it in every single if-statement, the "myIP" will never be accessible in any way in another scope (let's say, outside the if statement or even in another one). As such, I recommend the following

```
// Declare the myIp variable
string myIp = "";

if (osVer.StartsWith("10")) 
{
 MessageBox.Show("Windows 10");

// Make sure "myIP" isn't null before trying to use it (here, and on other places where you use it)
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myIp))
myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName).AddressList[2].ToString(); // Get the IP
}

else if (osVer.StartsWith("6"))
{
MessageBox.Show("Win7!");

// Make sure "myIP" isn't null before trying to use it (here, and on other places where you use it)
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myIp))
myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName).AddressList[3].ToString(); // Get the IP

}
else {
 // Make sure "myIP" isn't null before trying to use it (here, and on other places where you use it)
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myIp))
 myIP = "?";
```

This will define the myIp variable and make it accessible throughout the whole class or wherever you got this, and as long as you check your variables aren't null before trying to use them, you should be just fine.

Answer (score -2):

2 things.

1) You should declare my ip on the line after osVer, before the if. The variables in c# are block scoped, and so its not visible to the lines after your if else-if else, because you are declaring the variable in the conditional blocks.

`string myIP;`

2) You are not assigning myIP to anything in the final else statement. You should atleast assign it an empty string value, either when you declare it or in that final else. You can't have an unassigned variable.

Comment: is says, thanks for the feedback, votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score, i guess i only have 4 reputation..

Comment: @TerribleDev It's bad form to ask for rep. And just to be thorough you should also mention what will likely happen when he calls `IPAddress.Parse(myIP)` with a null `myIP`.

Comment: @slugster and worse form to call a new poster a troll when he in fact can't up-vote the answer.

Comment: just to be clear, this code segment exists within the code segment that defines the layout and positioning of a form, as there is label displaying the IP... however, when i call on this variable from the event handler of a button also on this form, it is not recognizable as well.. any tips?

Comment: @slugster You are right, I should have mentioned what happens when he calls IPAddress.Parse(<null value>); Thanks for mentioning the case I missed.

Comment: @slugster I personally, was not asking for an upvote. I just mentioned its good to upvote the answer. I did not realize it was "bad form" to ask for valid answers to be upvoted. 

I apologize if anyone's feelings were hurt, by my very snarky remark, however it was just that. Full of snark, and not a hateful in nature. Tone does not come through very well in written words, especially in such a limiting language as English.